# Spring bean java.lang.String gets set to null instead of the provided string when another BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring

I have the following bean definitions in the application context XML:

```
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.packt.lifecycle.HelloWorld">
</bean>

<bean name="message" class="java.lang.String">
   <constructor-arg value="testing" />
</bean>
```

When I run the code:

```
AbstractApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
System.out.println(context.getBean("message"));
```

It displays fine, that is, "testing". BUT, when I make the `helloWorld` bean implement BeanPostProcessor then the value of `message` bean becomes null. Is this a bug?

Comment: I am not understanding what is the relation between `helloWorld` and `message` bean here, why implementing `BeanPostProcessor` in `helloWorld` bean affecting the `message` bean.

Comment: I don't know why but it has for some reason. Sorry can't answer why because I'm not experienced with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. The 2 methods of the BeanPostProcessor must return the first argument. Instead I was returning null. I found the answer here: [I am using bean post processor, and it is giving null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726803/i-am-using-bean-post-processor-and-it-is-giving-null-pointer-exception)